# Column space and nullspace intersect trivially

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix where rank($A$) = rank($A^2$).

Show that the nullspace of $A$ and the column space of $A$ intersect trivially, i.e. $V $ = N(A) $\cap$ C(A) = $\{\textbf{0}\}$.

My solution is as follows
Nullspace is given as $\{\textbf{x}\mid A\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}\}$;

Column space is $\{A\textbf{u}\mid \textbf{u}\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.
Hence $A(A\textbf{x})=A(\textbf{0})=\textbf{0}\in V$, which is the trivial case.

How can I show $\textbf{0}$ is the only element in the intersection? Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition on the ranks of $A$ and $A^2$ imply that their nullspaces have the same dimension, by the rank-nullity theorem. The nullspace of $A$ is always a subspace of the nullspace of $A^2$, so the equality of their dimensions implies that in this case their nullspaces are exactly the same.

If some element $Au$ of the column space were also in the nullspace of $A$, then $A^2 u=0$. Thus $u$ is in the nullspace of $A^2$, and by the previous paragraph, we know $u$ is also in the nullspace of $A$. Thus, $Au=0$.